# Where does Gnome keep track of window size to use when starting applications?

Tags: gnome, window, preferences

For some reason my terminals insist on starting maximized since a couple of days. Which is neither a wanted behaviour nor especially useful on an UHD display. I might have closed a terminal window in maximized state and for some reason Gnome has saved that...where exactly?

Where are window properties for different applications saved and when? In my experience this behaves a little erratically anyway and I'd like to edit those preferences if "automatic mode" behaves weird.

---

Bionic Desktop with Gnome 3.28.2, Gnome-Terminal

Comment: Which Ubuntu official flavor, which Ubuntu version, which specific terminal app?

Comment: Bionic Desktop with Gnome 3.28.2, Gnome-Terminal

Comment: Add this information to the body of your question: version may be important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gnome does not keep track of window **size or state** when a program is running or is closed. The window size and state upon program start is controlled by the application itself. Some applications will remember their windows settings between launches, others won't. Some use gsettings to store window sizes, others use a text config file, others do not store that at all.

Gnome does not keep track of where windows are **positioned**. Instead, it (actually the window manager Mutter) determines the position based on some algorithm. By default, an algorithm is used, where windows are maximally placed on place that is still free, or stacked if no free desktop space is available. This behavior can be changed to center new windows by changing the setting "org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows", eventually using Gnome Tweaks which exposes that setting. Programs themselves also may or may not store coordinates of the windows and restore them when relaunched.

I am aware that this does not solve your current issue of the always maximized terminal, but it answers the question you asked, i.e., where these settings are stored.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of the `gnome-terminal` app, there is a setting for that in the user profile (preferences):

```
Gnome-terminal window
  > Hamburger menu button
    > Preferences
      > "Preferences" window > sidebar > current profile (marked by checkmark)
        > "Text" tab > "Text appearance" section
          > "Initial terminal size" form group
```

[image: terminal preferences screenshot]

Beyond this setting, it is also interesting whether the window shows up in the center of the screen, or or somewhat to the left, or entirely to the left... In the case of gnome-terminal, I don't know where that is regulated.

**Impact by Gnome Tweaks**

The Gnome Tweaks app offers a setting to start *every* window at the center of the screen:

```
> Tweaks app
  > "Windows" sidebar item
    > "Center New Windows" toggle
```

**Digging in gsettings**

If you install `dconf-editor`, you can find numerous cases where the window position is stored in specific apps' `gsettings` schema.

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then use the app's search feature: window-position related settings seem to come under the names of `window-position`, `window-state`, and `window-ratio`. So an useful search term in dconf is just `window-`.

Comment: If set this to 100x32 and it still set that way. Window's maximized to screen size. I'll have a look into dconf.

Comment: @Hinz Do you mean you have set it as such and the setting keeps being ignored and it still opens full screen?

Comment: yes, exactly. Same as if you'd pull the window to top of screen e.g.

Comment: Have you installed a new theme or gnome-shell theme recently? Otherwise look through `~/.bashrc` or `~./bash_profile` files?

Comment: If I unmaximize the terminal-window by pulling its title bar away from the screen's top, it takes on normal size for 100x32. No luck in dconf-settings. Nothing weird seems to be set for the terminal-app.

Comment: Do you run any specific app in the terminal when this happens? Vim and Gvim can impact it through their corresponding `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files through `lines` and `columns` keys.

Comment: No, didn't touch bashrc recently, and nothing running in the shell, just a prompt. Ah, well I'll have to live with it I guess.

Comment: my gnome-terminal on 22.04 is also exhibiting this behavior as of a few days ago. It's weird! Also not seeing anything in dconf.