# App window opening half in the monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Using Ubuntu 20.04 on a three-monitor display (Left-1440x900, Centre-1920x1080, Right-1440x900).
After a fresh install, I opened the System Monitor app and it appeared in the left monitor with the top quarter of the window outside the top of the screen. I could not use the mouse to access the title bar to move the window, nor access the window control buttons. I used Alt+F7 to with the arrow keys to move System Monitor into full view. Note: The monitors are displaying the correct resolution - the mouse stops at the tops and sides of the screen
Question: Where in the filesystem does the OS store the information about where to display a window (in this case System Monitor) and the size of that window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming stock Ubuntu 20.04 with Xorg Server and Mutter window manager.

---

**Window-positioning keyboard shortcuts** (best and quickest solution candidate):

The first task is to get the mis-positioned window focused. You can get it focused by using the Alt+Tab cycle, or, in some configurations, through clicks on the app's icon in the dock.

With the window focused, the combination of a modifier key + arrow keys can position it such that it gets resized to the active monitor's exact size.

This modifier on 20.04 by default is the left `Super` key (the left "Windows" key).

(On older releases, the modifier was the `Alt` key, and in 20.04, through user preferences, `Alt` can still be made that modifier. But it's not the default any more.)

`Super` + `up` arrow will maximize the window size on the active monitor.

`Super` + `left` / `right` arrows will move the window to the corresponding side of the active monitor.

Again, each of these will resize the window to match the active screen's size.

*Bonus:*

`Super` + `shift` + `left` / `right` arrows will move the window to the next adjacent monitor. (This however will not resize the window, and will keep its disturbing offset, even if on the other monitor.)

---

**Full-window-area click-drag:**

Holding down a modifier key during a click-dragging mouse gesture makes the entire surface of the window available for click-dragging (not just the header).

This modifier key used to be `Alt` on older releases, and left `Super` (the left-side "Windows" key) on recent releases. Try both.

---

**Tweaking the system monitor app's window geometry through `gsettings` API:**

(Note: this is not available for all apps. System monitor however has this feature.)

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor window-state
```

and

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor maximized
```

seem relevant.

But both of these seem to get updated every time you close the system monitor window. So after you have already recovered the window to a usable position with mouse, or cursors, or anyhow, there is no point in setting these; they will just get updated again.

With that said, here is a command capable of restoring the window; from the above it can be seen that it has to be issued while there is no window open for system monitor:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor window-state '(1000,800,50,50)'
```

Subsequently starting the app should place the window with the prescribed geometry.

See [more info about window-positions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315204/where-does-gnome-keep-track-of-window-size-to-use-when-starting-applications).