# Re-open windows at the same size and location?

Tags: 20.04

Running Ubuntu 20.04: When I close an application, I would like it to restart at the same window size and location the next time I start it, whether it is in the same session or several sessions later. It would seem logical for all applications to do that, but I can't figure out how to make it so. I often use applications in the same location on the screen and stacked with edges showing in a way that makes sense to me. It would help me if they defaulted to restarting in the same location they were closed.
Please help!
Joe

Comment: You could also study this thread: https://askubuntu.com/q/1315204/1157519

Comment: I know that you can set this up in KDE (Kubuntu) with the "Window Rules" settings, but I'm not sure that you can do this in GNOME, at least not with additional software.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at `Put Windows`, a gnome-shell extension, found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/.

[image]

Or `Arrange Windows`, at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1604/arrange-windows/.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps as I'm currently on 22.04, but I've found Smart Auto Move to just work!  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4736/smart-auto-move/